# File monitoring in osx 10.8.2 using python

Tags: python, multithreading, macos, file-io, win32com

I am using a file monitor to listen to the changes in a file using win32file monitor. This below code works fine on windows. This code does not work on mac osx. Any suggestions for making a file monitor on mac osx.

```
thread1 = myThread(1, tempFileName, tempLocation,selectedFileName)
thread1.start();    

    class myThread (threading.Thread):
                def __init__(self, threadID, fileName, directory, origin):
                    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                    self.threadID = threadID
                    self.fileName = fileName
                    self.daemon = True
                    self.dir = directory
                    self.originalFile = origin
                def run(self):
                    startMonitor(self.fileName, self.dir, self.originalFile)

    def startMonitor(fileMonitoring,dirPath,originalFile):
                    hDir = win32file.CreateFile (
                      dirPath,
                      FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
                      win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                      None,
                      win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
                      win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
                      None
                    )
                    readFlags = win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME  | \
                            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME   | \
                            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES | \
                            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE       | \
                            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | \
                            win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY
                    # Wait for new data and call ProcessNewData for each new chunk that's    written
                    while 1:
                        # Wait for a change to occur
                        results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW (
                                                                   hDir,
                                                                   1024,
                                                                   False,
                                                                   readFlags,
                                                                   None
                                                                   )
                        # For each change, check to see if it's updating the file we're interested in
                        for action, file_M in results:
                            full_filename = os.path.join (dirPath, file_M)
                            #print file, ACTIONS.get (action, "Unknown")
                            if len(full_filename) == len(fileMonitoring) and action == 3:
                                if os.path.exists(originalFile):
                                        encrypt_file(fileMonitoring,originalFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pywin32` (Python extensions for Windows)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) only works on Windows as the name suggests.

You can use [`watchdog`](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/). It support Mac OS X as well as Linux, Windows, FreeBSD.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. When a file is opened any file type, it should listen to the changes and call the encryption function. When the opened file is closed, it should return from the listener. So file monitoring is continuously active when a file is opened. I am unable to find this with watchdog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. It works in my case.

```
class ChangeHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

        def on_any_event(self, event):
            encrypt_file(key, tempFileName, selectedFileName,iv)

    def filemonitor(tempFileName,tempLocation):

        while 1:

            event_handler = ChangeHandler()
            observer = Observer()
            observer.schedule(event_handler, tempLocation, recursive=True)
            observer.start()
            try:
                while True:
                    time.sleep(1)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                observer.stop()
            observer.join()        

    Thread(target=filemonitor,args=(tempFileName,tempLocation,)).start()
```